# Koin has not been started in multi-modules project

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I am using Koin to inject some classes.

I followed Koin official doc but whenever I launch my application it crashes. My project is a multi-modules project but all my injections are used in the same module.

Definition of my Koin module:

```
val databaseModule = module {
    factory { provideIoDispatcher() }
    single { provideHerowDatabase(get()) }
    single { provideZoneDAO(get()) }
    single { providePoiDAO(get()) }
    single { provideCampaignDAO(get()) }
    single { provideZoneRepository(get()) }
    single { providePoiRepository(get()) }
    single { provideCampaignRepository(get()) }
}

private fun provideIoDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

/** and so on **/
```

Application class:

```
class DetectionApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration = Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
        .build()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@DetectionApplication)
            modules(listOf(databaseModule))
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="io.herow.sdk.detection">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application android:name=".DetectionApplication">

        <receiver android:name=".location.LocationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".geofencing.GeofencingReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".notification.NotificationReceiver" />

        <service
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location"
            tools:node="merge" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            tools:node="merge" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Entry point of my project

```
class HerowInitializer private constructor(val context: Context) : KoinComponent {

    //Koin
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher by inject()

    init {
        loadIdentifiers(context)
    }

    private fun loadIdentifiers(context: Context) {
        CoroutineScope(ioDispatcher).launch {
            
            /** code  **/
        }
    }
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Seeing the same behaviour for my multi-module project. Out of interest, have you added the Koin dependency to all your modules that provide dependencies? In my case, I'm attempting to make each module specify its own dependency injection as a module which is combined into one later on for Koin.

Comment: I fixed my issue later but yes I set Koin as a dependency in my build.gradle (project level). I never tried to do what you're trying to do, sorry :/